# Awk or grep question

Tags: awk, grep

I have this datafile

```
[abc]
def
ghi
[jkl]
[mno]
```

From this file; i can run grep and easily get all lines that have "[" in them. How can I get the contents of text inside "[]".

For example:

```
abc
jkl
mno
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/p' file
```

Explanation: -n suppresses the printing of each line to STDOUT, but the `/p` at the end of the regex re-enables this behavior causing all matching lines to be printed. The regex itself matches everything between brackets and replaces the entire line with it.

Comment: I've tried to explain most of it. The regex escapes the square brackets, enables grouping and matches any character repeating zero or more times, then a closing bracket. It then replaces the entire string with the grouping.

Comment: your answer will not work if the data is like what I have shown in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
sed -n 's/\[\([^]]*\)\]/\1/p'
```

or

```
awk -F "[][]" '$2 != "" {print $2}'
```

or

```
grep -Po '(?<=\[)[^]]*(?=])'
```

Comment: the `sed` solution might need enhancement if the data is like what I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

grep "\[" | sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/\]//'

Comment: i get error


sed: -e expression #1, char 5: Unterminated `s' command

Comment: I've tested using cygwin and it works. Take a look at the backslahs.

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can do it with awk

```
$ cat file
[abc]
def [ xxx]
ghi
[jkl]
[mno]
[zz
zzzz]


$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="]";FS="["}/\[/{print $NF }' file
abc
 xxx
jkl
mno
zz
zzzz
```

Ruby(1.9+)

```
 ruby -0777 -ne 'puts $_.scan(/\[(.*?)\]/m)' file
```

Or you can do it with just the shell

```
$ var=$(<file)
$ IFS="]"
$ set -- $var
$ for i in $@; do echo ${i##*[}; done
```